# Create a method to open a form using string text as form's name

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string contains a form name, I used the code below to find the form that has the desired name

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Form frm = (Form) asm.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApp1." + "myForm");
```

Then I used the code below to assign an event to a button to open that form

```
if (frm != null)
{
    btn.Click += new EventHandler((s, ev) => { MakeAndDisplayForm(() => frm); });
}
```

The MakeAndDisplayForm method is used to open any form and as below

```
private void MakeAndDisplayForm(Func<Form> CreateForm)
    {
        using (var form = CreateForm())
        {
          form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

the problem is whenever I run the code and find the required form, I can open it by clicking on the button by calling 'ShowDialog()' method, but as soon as I close it and run it again, the Application issue an exception that saying: 'Cannot access a disposed object.', 
I know the problem because I created the form as an object and whenever I closed it I disposed it, and the click's event can't call it anymore.
I've tried to add a "new" in MakeAndDisplayForm method to create a new form each time I click the button, but it says that you can't, because "form is a variable but is used as a type".

**Is there any way to create a new form each time I press the button?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once the form is open, why you are disposing it, simply hide the form and recall it whenever you need.

Comment: I haven't dispose it, but when close any form, the application dispose it by the default, I tried to change the close event and make it hide, but in the case of showdialog() method it doesn't work! I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Form frm = (Form) asm.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApp1." + "myForm");
```

inside the Click's event, so everytime I press the button, I search for the form then open it. thanks.